# Capybara - usage of applying has_xpath? on an apath with variable

Tags: capybara

There is the structure like:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="fieldRow">...</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="fieldRow">
      <div class="CheckBox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="fieldRow">...</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="fieldRow">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my script I am writing a loop for each of the 4 div's under div[@class='parent'] and aiming to click the checkbox if there is, i.e.
members = page.all(:xpath, '//div[@class='parent'])

```
members.each do |a|
  if **page.has_xpath?(a).find(:xpath, "div[@class='fieldRow']/div[@class='CheckBox']")**
    a.find(:xpath, "div[@class='fieldRow']/div[@class='CheckBox']").click
  end
end
```

However I can't look for the correct usage of has_xpath? with xpath including variable.
Please advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`has_xpath?` takes an XPath expression (not an element) and returns a boolean (true/false) based on whether there are any elements that match that expression within the current scope - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_xpath%3F-instance_method. Since it returns true/false you can't then call `find` on it. For the example you posted there's no need for XPath or checking for the existence of the elements, just find all the matching elements and call click on them.  Something like

```
page.all('div.parent div.fieldRow div.Checkbox').each { |cb| cb.click }
```

or

```
page.all('div.parent div.Checkbox').each { |cb| cb.click }
```

if the `fieldRow` class isn't something you really need to check.

Note: this assumes clicking the elements doesn't invalidate any of the other matched elements/change the page.

If you REALLY need to do it with the whole `members` and looping on them , using XPath, and checking for presence then it would be something like

```
members = page.all(:xpath, './/div[@class='parent'])
members.each do |a|
  if a.has_xpath?(:xpath, ".//div[@class='fieldRow']/div[@class='CheckBox']")
    a.find(:xpath, ".//div[@class='fieldRow']/div[@class='CheckBox']").click
  end
end
```

Note: the `.//` at the beginning of the XPath expressions is needed for scoping to work correctly - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap - which is an issue using CSS selectors doesn't have, so you should really prefer CSS selectors whenever possible.

Comment: Yes in the script I need to do something with the fieldRow classes, a.has_xpath? solved my problem.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @user8750496 I would still recommend the use of CSS (so `has_css?`) instead of XPath whenever possible - makes for much more readable code and simpler selectors.  Assuming the page is fully loaded when this is running, you may also want to pass `wait: 0` as an option to `has_xpath?`/`has_css?` otherwise it will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for the element to appear before returning false.